# What am I missing that is causing: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now?

Tags: php, mysqli, procedural-programming

The $recruitcheck/$badgecheck actually works, and it returns correctly, and it provides the verified echo, but I assume I am doing something incorrect with the store/bind/close stuff, as I am having some trouble figuring out exactly how it works.

The problem arises with the $emailcheck/$namecheck because it does not accurately return the query, and it sort of ends up bypassing to the $register phase where it returns the error echo, so $emailcheck/$namecheck are always false/0.

I had it working before, but I am trying to implement some security features, thus I added prepared statements, and I barely knew what I was doing before adding those, so I apologize if this question is not appropriate, or it is not enough information. If you comment, I will edit the post to be more relevant. Please, give me chance.

```
$recruitcheck = mysqli_prepare($maindb, "SELECT aurapass, recruitbadge FROM auras WHERE auraname = ?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($recruitcheck, "s", $recruitername);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($recruitcheck);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($recruitcheck, $passcheck, $badgecheck);
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($recruitcheck);
            if($passcheck == $recruitpass){
                if($badgecheck == "valid"){
                    mysqli_close($recruitcheck);
                    echo "<script>alert('Recruiter badge verified.')</script>";
                    $emailcheck = mysqli_prepare($maindb, "SELECT * FROM auras WHERE email = ?");
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($emailcheck, "s", $email);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($emailcheck);
                    mysqli_stmt_fetch($emailcheck);
                    $namecheck = mysqli_prepare($maindb, "SELECT * FROM auras WHERE auraname = ?");
                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($namecheck, "s", $auraname);
                    mysqli_stmt_execute($namecheck);
                    mysqli_stmt_fetch($namecheck);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($emailcheck)>0 || mysqli_num_rows($namecheck)>0){
                        die("<script>alert('New auraname/email is already taken.')</script>");
                    }
                    else{
                        mysqli_close($emailcheck);
                        mysqli_close($namecheck);
                        if($email == $emailconfirm){
                            $register = mysqli_prepare($maindb, "INSERT INTO auras (recruitername, recruitmethod, email, birthday, country, gender, auraname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
                            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($register, "sssisss", $recruitername, $recruitmethod, $email, $birthday, $country, $gender, $auraname);
                            mysqli_stmt_execute($register);
                            mysqli_close($register);
                            if(!$register) {
                                echo mysqli_error($maindb);
                                die("<script>alert('Error returned during registration: See bottom of page.')</script>");
                            }
                            else{
                            die("<script>alert('New aura registered successfully!')</script>");
```

$passcheck/$badgecheck are simply bind variables, and the only places they are called is where you see them here. Otherwise:

```
$recruitpass = cleaninput($_POST["recruitpass"]);
```

and

```
function cleaninput($info) {
            $info = trim($info);
            $info = stripslashes($info);
            $info = htmlspecialchars($info);
            return $info;}
```

The recruitcheck actually works, as it changes with incorrect versus correct input, but the code does not properly move on to the next checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `mysqli_close()` for `$emailcheck` and `$namecheck` queries before you call `mysqli_num_rows()` on them.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to say. @BaileyF I'd like to add a 101 debugging technique : cut some codes until it works, then put it back line by line. This is not the only technique, not always the best, but can be really useful for beginners and sometimes to find out quickly for the problem comes from.

Comment: I inserted a fetch, but it still does not run the $emailcheck/$namecheck.

Comment: @BaileyF:  Please show us the contents of `$passcheck`, `$recruitpass`, and `$badgecheck`.

Comment: I will try to find the exact error line, but it might be tomorrow before I post any findings. I appreciate the help this far.

Comment: Okay, there is no error following mysqli_close($requestcheck), but there is an error as soon as I try to prepare the $emailcheck, so I assume I am not closing $requestcheck correctly, if at all.

Comment: The Commands out of sync error was fixed by closing the $maindb connection rather than the individual $recruitcheck variable, so: mysqli_close($maindb) rather than mysqli_close($recruitcheck), but I think moving the mysqli_close() to afterward helped the situation too.